# Overlay on an image with a name

Tags: image, css, hover

I am trying to get an overlay over some images I have tried so many ways and I can't seem to get it over the image. The overlay either goes above or below, but won't go over the image. any help would be awesome!

[image: this is how my code is turning out]

Here is my code:

```css
.friend-profiles {
    font-family: "Lora", serif;
    width: 52%;
    padding-top: 15px;
}

.title-header {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    padding: 0 10px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid #dedede;
    box-shadow: -1px 1px 3px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    outline: none;
    height: 35px;
}

.sort {
    border: 1px solid #272727;
    padding: 1px 10px;
    font-size: 8px;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    text-indent: 1px;
    text-overflow: '';
    border-radius: 0;
}

.sort:focus {
    outline: none;
}

.friends-list{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}

.friend-profilePic {
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    width: 200px;
    height: 150px;
}

.box {
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px;
  box-shadow:inset 1px 1px 40px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.45);
  border-bottom:2px solid #fff;
  border-right:2px solid #fff;
  margin:5% auto 0 auto;
  background-size:cover;
  overflow:hidden;
}

.overlay    {  background:rgba(0,0,0,.75);
               text-align:center;
               padding:45px 0 66px 0;
               opacity:0;
               -webkit-transition: opacity .25s ease;}

.box:hover .overlay {
               opacity:1;}
```

```html
<div class="friend-profiles">
        <nav class="title-header">
            <a ui-sref="friend-search"><img src="/images/Icons/Search.svg"></a>
            <input class="search-friends" type="text" placeholder="Search For Friends" onfocus="this.placeholder=''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'Search For Friends'">
        </nav>

        <div class="friends-list">

        <div ng-repeat="results in userResults">
            <img ng-src="{{results.profileUrl}}" class="friend-profilePic">
            <div class="box">
              <div class="overlay">
                <p>test</p>
              </div>
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Do you just want to add text on image hover?

Comment: @SAM I actually want to add a name and eventually a button on the overlay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have added some element and style, that `.box` position to absolute.

```css
.friend-profiles {
    font-family: "Lora", serif;
    width: 52%;
    padding-top: 15px;
}

.title-header {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    padding: 0 10px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid #dedede;
    box-shadow: -1px 1px 3px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    outline: none;
    height: 35px;
}

.sort {
    border: 1px solid #272727;
    padding: 1px 10px;
    font-size: 8px;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    text-indent: 1px;
    text-overflow: '';
    border-radius: 0;
}

.sort:focus {
    outline: none;
}

.friends-list{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}

.friend-profilePic {
    width: 200px;
    height: 150px;
}

.picture-wrapper {
  position:relative;
  overflow:hidden;
}
.box {
  position:absolute;
  top:0;left:0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  box-shadow:inset 1px 1px 40px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.45);
  border-bottom:2px solid #fff;
  border-right:2px solid #fff;
  background-size:cover;
  overflow:hidden;
}

.overlay    {  background:rgba(0,0,0,.75);
               text-align:center;
               padding:45px 0 66px 0;
               opacity:0;
               -webkit-transition: opacity .25s ease;
width:100%;height:100%;
}

.box:hover .overlay {
               opacity:1;}
```

```html
<div class="friend-profiles">
        <nav class="title-header">
            <a ui-sref="friend-search"><img src="/images/Icons/Search.svg"></a>
            <input class="search-friends" type="text" placeholder="Search For Friends" onfocus="this.placeholder=''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'Search For Friends'">
        </nav>

        <div class="friends-list">

        <div ng-repeat="results in userResults" class="picture-wrapper">
            <img ng-src="{{results.profileUrl}}" class="friend-profilePic">
            <div class="box">
              <div class="overlay">
                <p>test</p>
              </div>
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your question in confusing but As much as I understood you want to show text or another image on image hover
Here is the code:

If it's not what meant tell me.

```css
 .hovereffect {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: default;
}

.hovereffect .overlay {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: rgba(75,75,75,0.7);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
}

.hovereffect:hover .overlay {
  background-color: rgba(48, 152, 157, 0.4);
}

.hovereffect img {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}

.hovereffect h2 {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 17px;
  padding: 10px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  -webkit-transform: translateY(45px);
  -ms-transform: translateY(45px);
  transform: translateY(45px);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
}

.hovereffect:hover h2 {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(5px);
  -ms-transform: translateY(5px);
  transform: translateY(5px);
}

.hovereffect a.info {
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 7px 14px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  background-color: transparent;
  opacity: 0;
  filter: alpha(opacity=0);
  -webkit-transform: scale(0);
  -ms-transform: scale(0);
  transform: scale(0);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  font-weight: normal;
  margin: -52px 0 0 0;
  padding: 62px 100px;
}

.hovereffect:hover a.info {
  opacity: 1;
  filter: alpha(opacity=100);
  -webkit-transform: scale(1);
  -ms-transform: scale(1);
  transform: scale(1);
}

.hovereffect a.info:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px #fff;
}
```

```html
<div style="width:350px; height:200px;">
    <div class="hovereffect">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/350x200" alt="">
        <div class="overlay">
           <h2>Hover effect</h2>
           <a class="info" href="#">link here</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is awesome, not 100% what I was looking for, but this will help moving forward. Amazing code here. I was looking for the answer below, but I would need to incorporate your button in there, just a little smaller.